# CO, NOx, HC plot with AFR Table

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, emissions

Can someone provide me with a lookup table (reliable of course), or a plot (with exact plot to scale) for CO, NOx, HC emission from a SI engine?

If possible, I am also looking for the same with for a diesel engine (for diesel, obviously not a plot with AFR).

Car is Hyundai I10

Comment: SI? Honda? What exact engine are you looking for? What range of rpm? This question is too broad to even begin to answer ... there are just too many variations which if we tried to account for, would leave you scratching your head. None of it would make a lick of sense.

Comment: @Paulster2   I think I may have answered his question.  Have a look at my answer and see what you think.

Comment: You can look up a "5 gas chart" for gasoline engines

Answer (score 6):

## Combustion Chemistry from Princeton

This isn't much of an answer but here is some data from a Princeton class related to Combustion Chemistry.  You will see that the table you are looking for is plotted.

[Here is the link to the PDF.](https://www.princeton.edu/ssp/64-tiger-cub-1/64-data/combustion-chemistry.pdf)

## Manufacturers of Emission Controls Association

Here is a study from Manufacturers of Emission Controls Association.  They have some plotting and graphs that seem relative to what you are seeking.

[Here is the link to the PDF](http://www.meca.org/resources/MECA_stationary_IC_engine_report_0515_final.pdf)

## Chemical Society Reviews

This document does not address exactly what you are looking for but it does have an excellent reference list that I suggest you parse.  There are many citations and some of them are very good.  If you aren't Chem101 level, it might not be for you.

[Here is the link to their study in PDF.](http://www.gradadm.ifsc.usp.br/dados/20102/FCM0102-5/Automotive%20fuels%20and%20internal%20combustion%20engines_a%20chemical%20perspective.pdf)

Hope this helpful.

Comment: I'll upvote you just for the outstanding try you always put into your answers. I would still expect the question to be closed, though.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Thanks for the answer. I went through the Princeton paper, but the problem is: 1. After AFR > 18, the CO% steadies to 0.5, but in my emission report (I did today), the CO% is 0.01. and 2. The HC curve says the min ppm of HC I can get is 70 ppm, but my emission test says that my HC is 19 ppm, which is kind of impossible to obtain from the curve. Can u help please. I stay in Delhi, India. Car is Hyundai i10

Comment: You need to provide much more information if you need help.

Comment: @SoumyaSen  For the question in your last comment.  I think you should create a new question for that and see if the community can assist you with it.